# Sub Menu nav in toggle button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

Using bootstrap 4 the photos I included so you can see the side nav menu on full screen and then only what shows on the mobile view I highlighted the menus.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLkDt.jpg

I have a nav bar and then I made a submenu nav on the left side of the website. So the main navbar has login and logout and the side nav menu offers subcategories etc.

Everything looks great on fullscreen.

But on mobile view, the main navbar with login and logout show in the toggle button the sub side nav menu disappears completely. I have tried to add it to the navbar but the issue is its always there, I need it only on mobile view.

I also tried to move it to the top below the navbar on mobile again it's always there. I need to know the way to only make items change positions when on mobile or fullscreen, or if someone knows another workaround.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Fav and touch icons -->



        <div class="header">
            <nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-site navbar-light bg-light navbar-expand-md"
                 role="navigation">
                <div class="container">

                <div class="navbar-identity">


                    <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>posts" class="navbar-brand logo logo-title">
                    <span class="logo-icon"><img class="navbar-brand" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>" width="100px" height="78px">
                    </span>Website<span> </span> </a>


              <button data-target=".navbar-collapse" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggler pull-right" type="button">

                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewbox="0 0 30 30" width="30" height="30" focusable="false"><title>Menu</title><path stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M4 7h22M4 15h22M4 23h22"/></svg>



                    </button>

</div>






                    <ul class="navbar-collapse collapse">


              <li class = "dropdown-item"><a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>posts"><strong>Posts</strong></a></li>




                        <?php if(!$this->session->userdata('logged_in')): ?>

             <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>users/login"><strong>Login</strong></a></li>

               <li class="dropdown-item" ><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>users/register"><strong></strong></a></li>




            <?php endif; ?>


                      <?php if($this->session->userdata('logged_in')) :?>

                                     <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>users/logout"><i class=" icon-logout"></i><strong> Log out</strong></a>
                                    </li>
                      <?php endif; ?>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li class="postadd nav-item"><a class="btn btn-block   btn-border btn-post btn-danger nav-link" href="<?php echo base_url();?>posts/create">Blogg</a>
                            </li>

                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <!--/.nav-collapse -->
                </div>
                <!-- /.container-fluid -->
            </nav>
        </div>
        <!-- /.header -->
    <div class="search-row-wrapper" style="background-image: url(images/bg.jpg)">
        <div class="inner">
        <div class="container ">
            <form action="#" method="GET">
                <div class="row">



                    <div class="col-md-3">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>


    <div class="main-container">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <!-- this (.mobile-filter-sidebar) part will be position fixed in mobile version -->
                <div class="col-md-3 page-sidebar mobile-filter-sidebar">
                    <aside>
                        <div class="sidebar-modern-inner">
                            <div class="block-title has-arrow sidebar-header">
                                <h5><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>posts"><span class="title">Categories</a></h5>
                            </div>
                            <div class="block-content categories-list  list-filter ">
                                <ul class=" list-unstyled">
                                    <li><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>posts"><span class="title">All Categories</span></a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>categories/posts/1243243"><span class="title">Female Escorts </span></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>categories/posts/23427874"><span class="title">Massage Parlors and Rub Downs</span></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>categories/posts/234324"><span class="title">Trans and Gay Escorts </span></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>categories/posts/15423465"><span class="title">Strip Clubs </span></a></li>

                                    </li>

                                </ul>
                            </div>  <!--/.categories-list-->

                            <div class="block-title has-arrow ">
                                <h5><a href="#">Location</a></h5>
                            </div>
                            <div class="block-content locations-list  list-filter ">
                                <ul class="browse-list list-unstyled long-list">
                                    <li><a href="sub-category-sub-location.html"> Miami </a></li>
                                    <li><a href="sub-category-sub-location.html"> Broward County </a></li>
                                    <li><a href="sub-category-sub-location.html"> West Palm Beach </a></li>
                                    <li><a href="sub-category-sub-location.html"> Florida Keys </a></li>
                                    <li><a href="sub-category-sub-location.html">Orlando </a></li>
                                    <li><a href="sub-category-sub-location.html"> Jacksonville</a></li>

                                </ul>
                            </div>






                        </div>




                    </aside>
                </div>
                <!--/.page-side-bar-->
                <div class="col-md-9 page-content col-thin-left">

                    <div class="category-list ">

                        <div class="tab-box ">

                            <!-- INSERTING THE CODE HERE TO LOOP-->

  <?php
                            if (empty($posts)) {
                              echo '<div class="text-center">';
                              echo "<h3>";
                                echo "<strong>";
                              echo "No matching results at this time.";
                                echo "</strong>";
                                echo "</h3>";
                                echo "</div>";

                              echo  '</div>
                                <!--/.tab-box-->


                                    <div class="pull-right col-xs-6 text-right listing-view-action"><span
                                            class="list-view active"><i class="  icon-th"></i></span> <span
                                            class="compact-view"><i class=" icon-th-list  "></i></span> <span
                                            class="grid-view "><i class=" icon-th-large "></i></span></div>

                                </div>
                                <!--/.listing-filter-->

                                <!-- Mobile Filter bar-->
                                <div class="mobile-filter-bar col-xl-12 ">


                                        <!-- Mobile Filter bar End-->


                                        <div class="tab-content">
                                        <div class="tab-pane  active " id="alladslist">
                                        <div class="adds-wrapper row no-margin">
                                        <div class="item-list">
                                        <div class="row">

                                            </div>



                                        </div>

                                        </div>';


                            } else {
                                foreach($posts as $post):{ ?>





                        </div>
                        <!--/.tab-box-->


                            <div class="pull-right col-xs-6 text-right listing-view-action"><span
                                    class="list-view active"><i class="  icon-th"></i></span> <span
                                    class="compact-view"><i class=" icon-th-list  "></i></span> <span
                                    class="grid-view "><i class=" icon-th-large "></i></span></div>
                            <div style="clear:both"></div>
                        </div>
                        <!--/.listing-filter-->

                        <!-- Mobile Filter bar-->
                        <div class="mobile-filter-bar col-xl-12  ">
                            <ul class="list-unstyled list-inline no-margin no-padding">
                                <li class="filter-toggle">
                                    <a class="">
                                        <i class="  icon-th-list"></i>

                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="menu-overly-mask"></div>
                        <!-- Mobile Filter bar End-->


                            <div class="tab-content">
                            <div class="tab-pane  active " id="alladslist">
                                <div class="adds-wrapper row no-margin">
                            <div class="item-list">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-2 no-padding photobox">
                                        <div class="add-image"><span class="photo-count"><i class="fa fa-camera"></i> </span>  <a href="<?php echo site_url('/posts/'.$post['slug']); ?>"><img class="thumbnail no-margin" src="<?php echo site_url();?>assets/images/posts/<?php echo $post['post_image']; ?>" alt="img"></a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <!--/.photobox-->
                                    <div class="col-md-7 add-desc-box">
                                        <div class="ads-details">
                                            <h5 class="add-title"><a href="<?php echo site_url('/posts/'.$post['slug']); ?>">

                                                <?php echo $post['title']." ---". $post['Number'];//TITLE OF THE POST>?></a></h5>


                         <span class="info-row">
                                    <span
                                            class="date"><i class=" icon-clock"> </i> </span> <small class="category">Location: <?php echo $post['Area']; ?> </small>

                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <!--/.add-desc-box-->
                                    <div class="col-md-3 text-right  price-box">

                                    </div>
                                    <!--/.add-desc-box-->
                                </div>

                            </div>
                            <!--/.item-list-->




                          <?php }endforeach; ?>
                        <?php } ?>


                                    <!--/.photobox-->

                                    <!--/.add-desc-box-->




                                        <!--/.item-list-->

                                </div>
                        </div>


                        <div class="tab-box"><a href=""> <i class=" icon-star-empty"></i>
                             </a></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="pagination-bar text-center">
                        <nav aria-label="Page navigation " class="d-inline-b">
                            <div class="pagination">


                        <?php echo $this->pagination->create_links(); ?>

                            </div>
                        </nav>
                    </div>
                    <!--/.pagination-bar -->

                    <div class="post-promo text-center">
                        <h2> Make a free account to post a add </h2>
                        <h5>Fast and easy</h5>
                        <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>posts/create" class="btn btn-lg btn-border btn-post btn-danger">Post a Free listing now</a>
                    </div>
                    <!--/.post-promo-->
                </div>
                <!--/.page-content-->

            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.main-container -->

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Honestly I didn't check in detail, usually html for bootstrap is a headache to read. However, I have something that might be of interest to your situation: css media queries.

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

The concept being that you can define, according to the client's width and height, different css properties. Beside defining css rules to different screen sizes, you can define different media such as print and so on. In this way, you can make an element to look a certain way when there is a lot of space, and in a different way when there is not so much space. That is what bootstrap is based on. Play around with it.

As a side note, I would recommend you to try isolate exactly the bits of code that are problematic. I usually try to re-write the code in order to have only the problem showing, and none of the unrelated stuff off. In this way you get better and more answers. ;)